# How do I calculate an integral that contains the floor function?

Tags: integration, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to get my head around Abel's summation formula ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula)), but I am confused about how to deal with an integral involving the floor function.

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3, ... , a_n, ...$ be a sequence of real or complex numbers, and define a partial sum function $A$ by

$$A(t) = \sum_{1 \le n \le t} a_n$$

Further, fix real numbers $x < y$ and let $\phi$ be continuously differentiable function on $[x, y]$. Then

$$\sum_{1 \le n \le x} a_n \phi(n) = A(x) \phi(x) - \int_1^x A(u) \phi '(u) \, du$$

*EXTRA INFO*: My aim is find a formula of this form for a sum $\sum_{1 \le n \le x} \phi(n)$. So (*back to original post*):

Let the sequence $a_n$ be $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1, ... $ . Then $\sum_{1 \le n \le x} a_n \phi(n) = \sum_{1 \le n \le x} \phi(n)$ and $A(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$. So,

$$\sum_{1 \le n \le x} \phi(n) = \lfloor x \rfloor \phi(x) - \int_1^x \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du$$

But how do I calculate the integral $\int_1^x \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du$? Obviously $\lfloor u \rfloor$ is a constant for any given value of $u$, but I don't know how to tackle the indefinite integral - not even for something as simple as $\phi(x) := x^2$. (Note that this is just an example of $\phi$; I am after a more general solution.)

Comment: One simple (but possibly inefficient) way to do it is to break up the range of integration into chunks (by linearity of integration) such that each chunk has $\lfloor u\rfloor$ as constant, and sum up the result - the results may even have a closed form summation formula

Comment: You can write $\int_1^x \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du = \int_1^2\lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du + \int_2^3\lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du + \cdots + \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x\lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du$ or $\int_1^21 \cdot \phi '(u) \, du + \int_2^3 2 \cdot \phi '(u) \, du + \cdots + \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x \lfloor x \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du.$ If you apply this to find $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2$ and expand everything out it amounts to re-writing the discrete sum in a different way - I don't think calculus is doing much work here, really.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. However, I am not after a re-expression of the sum over $\phi$ in terms of other sums, but a solution of the form implied by the Abel summation formula - i.e., involving the integral. I have updated my OP to make this clearer.

Comment: What kind of expression are you looking for? I do not think there is anything more simple than the integral itself for arbitrary $\phi$.

Comment: Would the approximation by sawtooth function be an approach? Just to give a complete different idea?

Comment: $$\int_0^n\lfloor u\rfloor \phi'(u)\,du=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k(\phi(k+1)-\phi(k))=n\,\phi(n)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\phi(k+1)$$ plus the last partial interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a useful guide [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Etracy/courses/AbelSummation) which contains several applications of Abel's summation formula where $a_n = 1$ for $n = 1,2,3,...$, and the integral terms therefore contains a floor function. The feature they all have in common is their use of the identity

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_1^x \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du &= \int_1^x \bigl(u - \{u\} \bigr) \phi '(u) \, du
\\&= \int_1^x u \phi '(u) \, du - \int_1^x \{u\} \phi '(u) \, du
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\{u\}$ denotes the fractional part of $u$.

The function $\int_1^x u \phi '(u) \, du$ can often be defined and, since $0 \le \{u\} < 1$, in many cases we can set limits on $\int_1^x \{u\} \phi '(u) \, du$.

The suggestion made in several comments, and in more detail by @Sayan Dutta, that one can break up the integral containing the floor function into

$$\int_1^x \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du = \int_1^2 \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du + \int_2^3 \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du + ... + \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du$$

while perfectly correct, will generally lead straight back to the original sum.

The advantage of noting that $\int_1^x \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du = \int_1^x u \phi '(u) \, du - \int_1^x \{u\} \phi '(u) \, du$ is that the two integrals on the right hand side can be dealt with separately, providing two distinct terms, neither of which are not directly related to the original summation. It is this separation of terms which allows us to express the summation in a different and potentially useful form.

**Example**

Let $H_x = \sum_{1 \le n \le x} \frac{1}{n}$ be the harmonic number function. Set $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $a_n = 1$ for all $n = 1,2,3,...$.

Splitting the integral into unit steps produces

$$\begin{aligned}
H_x &= \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} - \int_1^x \frac{\lfloor u \rfloor}{u^2} \, du
\\&= \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} - \biggl( \int_1^2 \frac{\lfloor u \rfloor}{u^2} \, du + \int_2^3 \frac{\lfloor u \rfloor}{u^2} \, du + \int_{3}^4 \frac{\lfloor u \rfloor}{u^2} \, du + ... \biggr)
\\&= \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} - \biggl( 1 \bigl( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{1} \bigr) + 2 \bigl( \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} \bigr) + 3 \bigl( \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{3} \bigr) + ... \biggr)
\\&= \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ...
\\&= \sum_{1 \le n \le x} \frac{1}{n}
\\&= H_x
\end{aligned}
$$

On the other hand, writing $\lfloor x \rfloor = x - \{x\}$ gives us

$$\begin{aligned}
H_x &= \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} + \int_1^x \frac{\lfloor u \rfloor}{u^2} \, du
\\&= \frac{x - \{x\}}{x} + \int_1^x \frac{u - \{u\}}{u^2} \, du
\\&= 1 - \frac{\{x\}}{x} + \int_1^x \frac{1}{u} \, du - \int_1^x \frac{\{u\}}{u^2} \, du
\\&= 1 - \frac{\{x\}}{x} + \log x - \int_1^x \frac{\{u\}}{u^2} \, du
\\&= 1 - \frac{\{x\}}{x} + \log x - \biggl( \int_1^\infty \frac{\{u\}}{u^2} \, du - \int_x^\infty \frac{\{u\}}{u^2} \, du \biggr)
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $\{x\} = O(1)$ we can write $\frac{\{x\}}{x} = \frac{O(1)}{x} = O \bigl(\frac{1}{x} \bigr)$ and (after checking for issues of convergence)

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_x^\infty \frac{\{u\}}{u^2} \, du &= \int_x^\infty \frac{O(1)}{u^2} \, du
\\&= O(1)\int_x^\infty \frac{1}{u^2} \, du
\\&= O(1) \frac{1}{x}
\\&= O \bigl(\frac{1}{x} \bigr)
\end{aligned}
$$

So, now we have

$$H_x = \log x + 1 - \int_1^\infty \frac{\{u\}}{u^2} \, du + O \bigl(\frac{1}{x} \bigr)$$

Here, $1 - \int_1^\infty \frac{\{u\}}{u^2} \, du$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma = 0.5772156649...$. Thus

$$H_x = \log x + \gamma + O \bigl(\frac{1}{x} \bigr)$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x$ is NOT an integer
\begin{align*}
&\int_1^x \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du \\
= &\int_1^2 \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du + \int_2^3 \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du + \dots \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor-1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du +\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du\\
=&1\cdot \int_1^2 \phi '(u) \, du + 2\cdot \int_2^3 \phi '(u) \, du +\dots (\lfloor x \rfloor-1)\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor-1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \phi '(u) \, du +\lfloor x \rfloor\cdot\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x \phi '(u) \, du\\
=&(\phi(2)-\phi(1))+2(\phi(3)-\phi(2))+\dots +(\lfloor x \rfloor-1)(\phi(\lfloor x \rfloor)-\phi(\lfloor x \rfloor-1))+\lfloor x \rfloor (\phi(x)-\phi(\lfloor x \rfloor))\\
=&-\phi(1)+(\phi(2)-2\cdot \phi(2))+(2\cdot \phi(3)-3\cdot \phi(3))+\dots +(\lfloor x \rfloor\phi(\lfloor x \rfloor)-(\lfloor x \rfloor-1)\phi(\lfloor x \rfloor))+\lfloor x \rfloor\phi(x)\\
=&-\phi(1)-\phi(2)-\phi(3)-\dots -\phi(\lfloor x \rfloor)+\lfloor x \rfloor\phi(x)
\end{align*}

The first equality is due to linearity of integral, and the second one is due to Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

If $x$ is an integer, the last term won't be counted.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Sayan, plugging this into the summation formula gives

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{1 \le n \le x} \phi(n) &= \lfloor x \rfloor \phi(x) - \int_1^x \lfloor u \rfloor \phi '(u) \, du
\\&= \lfloor x \rfloor \phi(x) - \biggl(-\phi(1)-\phi(2)-\phi(3)-\dots -\phi(\lfloor x \rfloor)+\lfloor x \rfloor\phi(x) \biggr)
\\&= \lfloor x \rfloor \phi(x) + \biggl(\phi(1)+\phi(2)+\phi(3)+\dots +\phi(\lfloor x \rfloor)-\lfloor x \rfloor\phi(x) \biggr)
\\&= \phi(1)+\phi(2)+\phi(3)+\dots +\phi(\lfloor x \rfloor)
\\&= \sum_{1 \le n \le x} \phi(n)
\end{aligned}
$$

True... but not a new expression.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward wait a moment. At first I thought you only wanted to calculate that integral (my fault of course). Now, that I read the question properly, I have some questions regarding your question. In the actual formula that you have written, I think there should be a $-A(x)\phi(x)$ (in your case $-A(1)\phi(1)$) term- is there any reason to assume that to be $0$? Also, if I understand it properly, what you want is a general formula for $\sum \phi(n)$ in terms of $\phi$. If that's right, I don't see any reason to even think it's possible to find such an expression...

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward ... What this summation formula does is it converts a discreet sum into an integral (continuous sum). I don't see any reason to believe that it's possible to use this formula to find any general sum you want. Just scroll down a bit in the link you have given, and look at their treatment of the harmonic series. When you solve the integral on the RHS, what you get is the LHS back. Because there's really no hope to find an explicit formula for it. I hope I could make myself clear.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward if you feel like I couldn't get your question properly, please feel free to say that.

Comment: Hi @Sayan Dutta, thanks for the feedback. Regarding the examples (such as harmonic series) on the page I linked to, you say "When you solve the integral on the RHS, what you get is the LHS back." This is true - _provided you use the technique you outlined_ in order to resolve the integral. I was looking for a technique which would resolve the integral more productively. What is the point of the web page (or the Abel summation method!) if all it says is $\sum_{1 \le n \le x} \phi(n) = \sum_{1 \le n \le x} \phi(n)$? In fact, why have a whole section on the case $a_n = 1$?

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward if you look into it like this, then every formula says LHS=LHS. The thing is Abel's summation just provides you a different way to look into the same thing- it establishes the fact that the discreet summation on the LHS is the same as the continuous sum on the RHS. Now, you asked "what's the point then?". Well, whenever you can change a sum into an integral, you can say a lot of things about it in particular cases. For example, the harmonic series cannot be solved, but using Abel's sum, you can say that $H_x=\ln(x)+\gamma+\mathcal O \left(\frac 1x\right)$ which means...

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward ... as you add more and more terms, you go on getting a value close to $\ln(x)+\text{(a constant)}$. Another example can be the zeta function where you can use Abel sum (and some more) to derive $\zeta(s)=\frac s{s-1}-s\int_1^\infty \frac {\{t\}}{t^{s+1}}dt$. This tells you where the pole of $\zeta$ at $s=1$ comes from. You can also check the trivial zeroes of $\zeta$ if you have this form at hand. The point is in both cases (and there are innumerable more), changing the discreet sum into an integral gave you lots of information that weren't available otherwise.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward I hope I could explain "the point of" looking at something from a different angle. Also, returning to the main question, just think about it. Do you really think it's possible to find a general formula of $\sum \phi$ for any $\phi$? Mathematicians have been trying for centuries only for the harmonic function! If somebody could really solve the question you asked, he would immediately be a superstar in mathematics :)

Comment: Hi @Sayan Dutta. I do understand, I promise! Of course it is about looking at things a different way - precisely what I was hoping to achieve - and of course there can be no universal formula for some abstract $\phi$… But my question was, is there a way to tackle an integral involving the floor function that doesn’t just kick you straight back to the LHS in terms of its formulation - in other words, I was _precisely_ seeking a different way of looking at it. Breaking up the integral makes it a sum and removes the continuous nature of integrals. (Continued in next comment)

Comment: You offer the harmonic series and zeta functions as examples of not doing that… but surely the method you have proposed doesn’t lead to those interesting results. So, how were they reached?

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward yes, I understand your point. But, I still don't have hopes to get any more in another answer. If there would have been something non-trivial that can be said about a general $\phi$, you would have found it on the top of any website you opened. I'll bookmark this question amd wait to see if anything better comes to it. It was a nice question though.

Comment: Thanks @Sayan Duttan. It’ll do likewise and mark it as answered if nothing else comes up. In the meantime, could you perhaps point me towards resources that show me how the integral was tackled to get the results you mentioned for applying the Abel summation formula to the zeta and harmonic functions? I’m keen to learn!

Comment: Aha! One example is here: < https://www.cantorsparadise.com/the-abel-summation-formula-94f8b8d223b9 >

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward actually, I told them from memory. But, I remember reading the link you gave a few months back. I'll search for more such interesting links and let you know if I  can find them.